# Chart to Image via Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Is there anyway to send the raw Data and converted to chart and downloaded as Image through Google Drive API using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the Google Charts image API.

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts

http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/

You can save those images to Google Drive easily using the Drive API.